# Did I accidentally delete all my thumbnails and entire desktop?

Tags: windows, cache, windows-10, command-line, thumbnails

This is a bit different from my usual posts. I may have messed up badly. I was having a problem where my thumbnails for photos (jpg, png, etc., file type didn't matter), weren't showing up. Seemed like a relatively uncommon issue, but I tracked down a source which stated I could run this code in command prompt to clear my icon cache:

```
ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache

taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F

DEL "%localappdata%\IconCache.db" /A

shutdown /r /f /t 00
```

When I did this, not only were my thumbnails deleted, but so was everything on my start menu at the bottom of my screen, my entire desktop, shortcuts, background, etc. I think this can be solved by a simple reboot, but I don't want to close the only programs I have open (browser and command prompt), only to restart my PC and find out I've broken my computer and can't do anything. If it's as simple as a restart, awesome. If not, please let me know what to do to save my PC.

Comment: You should (at least) restart explorer.exe. That's probably all the problem here.

Comment: Should I do that without restarting my computer?

Comment: Yes, try without restarting - won't hurt!

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Still have my original problem with no thumbnails on files, but that's a much better one to have.

Comment: No problem. I may have done this before... Note that this question is going to be closed as off-topic because its not really fitting the type of questions for StackOverflow. But don't take it personally!  [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: From your directions above a restart (or at least shutdown) appears to be required to complete the process. After shutting down you may find your problem is completely fixed. This is assuming the instructions you are following are the solution. To that I can't comment.